# Are Maxwell's equations valid in a rotating frame?

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, coordinate-systems, relativity, maxwell-equations

Maxwell's equations are covariant under Lorentz transformations. Are they covariant under going to a rotating frame and if not how do they look?

Answer (score 1):

1. The [general covariant Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime) transform covariantly under general coordinate transformations.
2. Therefore if we start with [Maxwell's equations in Minkowski space in an inertial frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism), it is in principle straightforward to work out how the Maxwell's equations become in an accelerated reference frame, e.g. a rotating reference frame. We leave that exercise to the reader.